# Simplejwt don't appear on importation options

Tags: django, jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I had installed djangorestframework-simplejwt with pip, so had i configure settings.py file for to use it, but, when i try to import the package, it doesn't has showing in importable package list.

```
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication', 
    ),
```

The importations list:

[image: Importation available list]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply rebuild all the project. Now, runed fine!